# Making a program/game launcher on windows PCs

Tags: c#, windows

I would like to make a windows application, for a gaming club/internet caffe, which would run when Windows starts, cover the whole screen, including the taskbar, and prompt the user to log in. Regular users would be able to play games and use browsers and skype, while only the admin would have access to the hard drive and the desktop.
I would be targeting the Windows XP operating system, and would like to use C#.

I have a couple of problems with starting this project:

1) How to make the application cover/hide the entire desktop and taskbar and prevent the users from minimizing the application or starting the task manager and using it to terminate the application?

2) How do I make sure that, upon Windows startup, my application receives a high priority status and is the first one to launch- even before some of the Windows services get started? Again, I wouldn't want users rebooting the PCs and terminating the app with the task manager.

3) Is there anything I should know about Windows security policies, like some user permission settings required to be set in order for my program to work in the way described above?

I know this is not a question containing any code, but answers to these questions are key for starting to work on the project.

Comment: You are better off not even trying to do this. Instead, create a user with limited rights to only do what you want them to do.

Comment: Internet cafe + Windows XP is an accident waiting to happen. Support for Windows XP has ended, security patch frequency is decreasing to zero. Also search for "kiosk mode", you can replace Explorer.exe (the shell) with your own program. Then still the entire computer is vulnerable unless you work with group policies and so on to restrict the user even more.

Comment: I agree with @AndrewBarber this is more of a System Administration problem than a programming problem.

Comment: @Romoku I understand what you mean, yet stackoverflow seemed like the better board to post than Programmers or SuperUser. 
Windows XP is not my choice really, I will try to persuade the owners to reconsider their OS choice. 
CodeCaster, thanks for the search term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use a custom shell (your program).
Please check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479087.aspx

Comment: I like this answer, but I will wait a while before accepting it as the correct one. I will read this tutorial, thanks. +1